# Trouble sending textboxes and radiobutton value from 1st window to the 4th window C# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I got four windows.

1. Window1 has Textboxes and radiobuttons.
2. Basing on window1 , window2 opens.
3. basing on window2 , window 3 opens.
4. and window4 opens on basis of window1 information but the button is on window3 which opens window4.

what i am trying to do is to send window1 information to window3 so that i can open window4.
but i am unable to do it. 
i know how to pass values from one form to the second one. but this is complex and i tried it.
I have even tried the following link as well  please enlighten me with the answer.

https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/370098/hold-a-text-box-string-to-another-window-form

Window2 opening Code:

```
   if ((SeismicLevel_TextBox.Text == "Low") && (LevelOfPerformance_LS_RadioButton.IsChecked == true))
        {
            Region_of_Low_Seismicity t1_1 = new Region_of_Low_Seismicity();
            t1_1.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Window 3:

```
     Window3 w3 = new Window3();
        s.ShowDialog();
```

Window 4 but the button lies on window 3:

```
   if ((w1.SeismicLevel_TextBox.Text == "Low") && (w1.LevelOfPerformance_LS_RadioButton.IsChecked == true))
        {
            Window4 W4 = new Window4();
            W4.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Comment: How about using a shared viewmodel on app level that is used on all separate windows? Partly as @horHAY suggests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you would want to create a `ViewModel` for each Window, and then inject Window1's `ViewModel` into the other three via `Dependency Injection`. Though, for the sake of getting this working (and assuming you are not familiar with MVVM concepts yet), you can simply do the following:

As shown below, just create a `POCO` that is passed into the constructor of Window3 upon opening. The `POCO` will be populated with the control values from Window1. You will need to update the constructor for Window3, but it's as simple as adding an new parameter to its constructor.

```
 // POCO to store Window1 info
 public class Window1Values
 {
    public string TextBoxValue1 { get; set; }
    public bool CheckBoxValue1 { get; set; }
 }

 // Update Window 3 Ctor to look like the following, simply just add a parameter to the existing Ctor
 //
 public Window3(Window1Values window1Values)
 {
    // ...
 }

 // When Window 3 is going to open, do the following
 //
 var w3 = new Window3(new Window1Values
 {
    TextBoxValue1 = myTextBox.Text;
    CheckBoxValue1 = myCheckBox.IsChecked;  
 });
 w3.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would pass parameters through the pages.

For example, I'm a bit rusty but you should call a navigator to `PageName()`. So, pass arguments like `PageName(ButtonVal, Text)` and give `PageName()` a constructor accepting everything passed to it, and everything subsequent pages need.

Comment: can u please explain it a bit.

Comment: Alright, so when you go from Page1 to Page2, it should be a call like `Navigator.NavigateTo(new Page2());`. Inside that call, make it `Navigator.NavigateTo(new Page2(ButtonValForPage3, ButtonValForPage4));` and in Page2's constructor, assign variables to the passed values.

Comment: please excuse me if i am wrong but i am using window. not pages. 
sorry a bit new. But can i do this with window? or its just for page?

Comment: It should work with windows too, but horHAY's solution is probably easier/cleaner to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters would be a good idea, but it could get messy having to pass the same data through multiple windows. Instead an option could be to create a "Storage" class which you can save data to and access later on in the program.

```
public class Storage
{
    public static string textBoxValue1 { get; set; }
    public static bool checkBoxValue1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i have made a class. get the value of textbox and radiobuttons and then set it into window3 button to open window4. 
this method was explained in some question i was looking into but it didnot help. may be i am wrong

Comment: Can you post the code from your first form, showing you opening the 2nd form

Comment: `if ((SeismicLevel_TextBox.Text == "Low") && (LevelOfPerformance_LS_RadioButton.IsChecked == true))
            {
                Region_of_Low_Seismicity t1_1 = new Region_of_Low_Seismicity();
                t1_1.ShowDialog();
            }`